# Track unowned/Drop Ship inventory in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Here is what we are trying to do:

We want to track our vendors Drop Ship inventory which we do not own in NetSuite and be able to use the inventory feed from NetSuite to feed our eCommerce channels for both our owned and unowned inventory.

Here is what we've tried:

1- Enabled multi-location inventory
2- Created a "Drop Ship" location
3- Did an inventory adjustment to allocate inventory to that location

Here is the main issue we are facing:

The inventory should not show up on our balance sheet as we do not actually own it. In the scenario above, our inventory feed works as it should. However, the inventory shows up on our balance sheet.

Any assistance on how to get this to work without having the inventory shown on our balance sheet would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could set cost to zero on the item record to reduce the balance sheet value to zero.  To correctly show COGS on your P&L, you would need to add a cost on POs for each drop ship item.

To partially automate the PO process, create a custom column field that stores cost.  When a PO is created or on a schedule, use a saved search email notification that includes an import ready CSV with Internal ID, Line ID, the custom cost field and a link to a saved CSV import in the body of the email.  When you get the email notification, click the link and proceed to import the attached file with the correct item cost.